# How to make arrow narrower vertically with css?

Tags: html, css, hover

[image]

How can this shape and hover effect be made using CSS? I am able to make this shape but not able to add the hover effect. Anyone, please suggest me.

This is my code

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help

```css
.my-icon {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.my-icon > i {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 0;
    border: 2.69em solid transparent;
    border-left: 2.69em solid #efefef;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
}

.my-icon > i+i {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    border: 1.5em solid #efefef;
    border-bottom: 1.5em solid #efefef;
    left: 0em;
    top: 1.2em;
    display: inline;
}

.my-icon:hover i:nth-child(2) {
 border: 1.5em solid red;
 color: #fff;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.my-icon:hover i:first-child {
 border-left: 2.69em solid red;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
  <i class="my-icon">
    <i></i>
    <i>Item</i>
  </i>
```